# Что обозначает символ % в js

Tags: javascript

Я начинающий любитель программирования на javascritp! Что обозначает символ % в js?

Comment: @Denisoed здесь не принято отправлять в гугл. Вопрос простой, но тем не менее новичкам полезный. Не все же профи ;-)

Comment: Интересно где проходит граница между «не все профи» и «не удосужился почитать букварь»?

Comment: @AlexeyTen заметьте, что буквари точно так же нужны и печатаются, и по сути Денисоед дает ссылку как-раз на букварь. Так почему бы сразу не включить "букварь" в базу знаний SO ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### [Остаток от деления (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)

> Бинарный оператор. Оператор возвращает целый остаток от деления левого операнда на правый. Возвращаемое значение всегда получает знак делимого, а не
>   делителя.  Он использует встроенную функцию `modulo`, для получения
>   результата, которая является целочисленным остатком деления `var1` на
>   `var2` — например — `var1 modulo var2`.

### Синтаксис

Оператор: `var1 % var2`

### Примеры

```
12 % 5 // 2
-1 % 2 // -1
NaN % 2 // NaN
1 % 2 // 1
2 % 3 // 2
-4 % 2 // -0
5.5 % 2 // 1.5
```

---

Дополнительная ссылка: [Арифметические операторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за спокойный рассудительный ответ на мой незадачливый вопрос!!!

Comment: @shiklgroober, Если один из ответов решил Вашу проблему или помог Вам в поиске решения больше других, отметьте его принятым (нажмите повторно, чтобы отменить).

Answer (score 2):

Остаток от деления:
`10 % 5 = 0`
`10 / 5 = 2`, остатка нет
`10 % 3 = 1`, 9 делится на 3 без остатка, если делить 10 / 3, то остаток будет 1.

Answer (score 2):

Символ % в Javascript используется в математических операциях. Возвращает остаток от деления

```
8 % 3 // 2

7 % 2 // 1

-7 % 2 // -1 (результат всегда имеет такой же знак, как у первого операнда)
```

Answer (score 1):

% - оператор взятия остатка, результатом a % b является остаток от деления a на b.

Например:

6 % 3 = 0, остаток от деления 6 на 3

5 % 2 = 1,  остаток от деления 5 на 2

Comment: Не вижу, чем бы ваш ответ принципиально отличался от двух уже данных ранее.